# How to perform an operation on a 3D array and a matrix whilst returning a 3D array?

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, sapply

In R, let's have an array and a matrix:

```
a <- array(rep(1:3, each = 4), dim = c(2, 2, 3))
b <- matrix(seq(0, 1, length.out = 6), nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
```

I want to use an function that utilises matrices from `a` along the 3rd dimension and columns in `b` as its two arguments. For this example, we can assume that my function is:

```
myfunc <- function(x, y) { x * y }
```

I want the operation to return a 3D array. My current solution is to use `sapply` for indices and transform the resulting list into an array subsequently:

```
res <- sapply(1:dim(a)[[3]], FUN = \(x) myfunc(a[, , x], b[, x]), simplify = FALSE) 
res <- abind::abind(res, along = 3)
```

Is there another way how to achieve this operation that would directly result in a 3D array? I experimented with `sweep`, but failed.

Comment: Try `sapply(seq_len(dim(a)[3]), \(x) myfunc(a[, , x], b[, x]), simplify='array')`, or transpose (see [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76714729/6574038)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach is to change your 3D array and matrix into lists and use `mapply`. Here I wrote a simple function (`to_list()`) which does the array to list transformation (by default along the last array dimension).

```r
to_list <- function(x, along=length(dim(x))) {
  apply(x, along, identity, simplify=F)
}

res <- mapply(myfunc, to_list(b), to_list(a), SIMPLIFY=F)
res <- sapply(res, identity, simplify='array')
```

The `sapply` line does the same thing as your `abind` line.

Comment: It seems that I can simply use `sapply` with the `simplify = "array"` argument. This is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

We can transpose multidimensional arrays using `aperm`.

```
f <- \(A, m) aperm(aperm(A, c(3, 2, 1))*as.vector(t(m)), c(2, 3, 1))

f(a, b)
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  0.0  0.0
# [2,]  0.2  0.2
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  0.8  0.8
# [2,]  1.2  1.2
# 
# , , 3
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  2.4  2.4
# [2,]  3.0  3.0

stopifnot(all.equal(res, f(a, b), check.attributes=FALSE))  ## res from OP
```